# MonoTouch Binding Project Native linking failed. MT5202

Tags: binding, xamarin.ios

I have the following error from the build output when using a library I have linked through a MonoTouch linking project.

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:

The header file is as follows (Left out the eums for space)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AudioUnit/AudioUnit.h>
#import <ExternalAccessory/ExternalAccessory.h>

@interface MTSCRA : NSObject <NSStreamDelegate> 
{ 
@private

    NSString *cardIIN;
    NSString *cardData;
    NSString *cardLast4;
    NSString *cardName;
    NSString *cardExpDate;
    NSString *cardServiceCode;
    NSString *cardStatus;
    NSString *responseData;
    NSString *maskedTracks;
    NSString *stdTrack1;
    NSString *stdTrack2;
    NSString *stdTrack3;
    NSString *encryptedTrack1;
    NSString *encryptedTrack2;
    NSString *encryptedTrack3;
    NSString *encryptionStatus;
    NSString *maskedTrack1;
    NSString *maskedTrack2;
    NSString *maskedTrack3;
    NSString *trackDecodeStatus;
    NSString *encryptedMagneprint;
    NSString *magneprintStatus;
    NSString *deviceSerialNumber;
    NSString *deviceSerialNumberMagTek;
    NSString *encrypedSessionID;
    NSString *deviceKSN;
    NSString *deviceFirmware;
    NSString *deviceName;
    NSString *deviceCaps;
    NSString *deviceStatus;
    NSString *tlvVersion;
    NSString *devicePartNumber;
    NSString *capMSR;
    NSString *capTracks;
    NSString *capMagStripeEncryption;
    NSString *maskedPAN;
    NSString *additionalInfoTrack1;
    NSString *additionalInfoTrack2;
    NSString *responseType;
    NSString *batteryLevel;
    NSString *swipeCount;
    //NSArray  *aryCardData;
    //NSArray  *aryMaskedTracks;



    AudioUnit                   rioUnit;
    AURenderCallbackStruct      inputProc;  

    AudioStreamBasicDescription thruFormat;
    AudioBufferList             bufferlist;
    AudioBuffer                 buf;
    AudioBuffer                 buf1;
    BOOL                        isDeviceConnected;
    long eventMask;
    long devCapabilities;

    Byte *commandBits;
    int commandBitsIndex;

    EAAccessory * _accessory;
    EASession *   _session;
    EAAccessoryManager *eaAccessory;
    NSMutableString *dataFromiDynamo;
    NSMutableString *deviceProtocolString;
    NSMutableString *configParams;


    enum MTSCRADeviceType devType;
@public    


}

//Initialize device
-(BOOL) openDevice; 

//Close device
-(BOOL) closeDevice;


//Retrieves if the device is connected
- (BOOL) isDeviceConnected;

//Retrieve Masked Track1 if any
- (NSString *) getTrack1Masked;

//Retrieve Masked Track2 if any
- (NSString *) getTrack2Masked;

//Retrieve Masked Track3 if any
- (NSString *) getTrack3Masked;

//Retrieves existing stored Masked data, only supported for iDynamo, it will return a empty string in audio reader
- (NSString *) getMaskedTracks;

//Retrieve Encrypted Track1 if any
- (NSString *) getTrack1;

//Retrieve Encrypted Track2 if any
- (NSString *) getTrack2;

//Retrieve Encrypted Track3 if any
- (NSString *) getTrack3;

//Retrieve Encrypted MagnePrint, only supported for iDynamo, it will return a empty string in audio reader
- (NSString *) getMagnePrint;

//Retrieve MagnePrint Status, only supported for iDynamo, it will return a empty string in audio reader
- (NSString *) getMagnePrintStatus;

//Retrieve Device Serial Number
- (NSString *) getDeviceSerial;

//Retrieve Device Serial Number created by MagTek
- (NSString *) getMagTekDeviceSerial;

//Retrieve Firmware Vsersion Number
- (NSString *) getFirmware;

//Retrieve Device Name
- (NSString *) getDeviceName;

//Retrieve Device Capabilities
- (NSString *) getDeviceCaps;

//Retrieve Device Status
- (NSString *) getDeviceStatus;

//Retrieve TLV Version
- (NSString *) getTLVVersion;

//Retrieve Device Part Number
- (NSString *) getDevicePartNumber;

//Retrieve Key Serial Number
- (NSString *) getKSN;

//Retrieve individual tag value, only supported in audio reader
- (NSString *) getTagValue: (UInt32)tag;

//Retrieve MSR Capability
- (NSString *) getCapMSR;

//Retrieve Tracks Capability
- (NSString *) getCapTracks;

//Retrieve MagStripe Encryption Capability
- (NSString *) getCapMagStripeEncryption;

//Send Commands To The Device
- (void) sendCommandToDevice:(NSString *)pData; 

//Sets the protocol String for iDynamo
- (void) setDeviceProtocolString:(NSString *)pData; 
//Sets the config params for SDK
- (void) setConfigurationParams:(NSString *)pData; 

//Setup the events to listen for
- (void) listenForEvents:(UInt32)event;

//Retrieves the Device Type
- (int) getDeviceType;

//Retrieves the Length of teh PAN
- (int) getCardPANLength;

//Retrieve Session ID, only supported for iDynamo, it will return a empty string in audio reader
- (NSString *) getSessionID;

//Retrieved the whole Response from the reader
- (NSString *) getResponseData;

//Retrieves the Name in the Card
- (NSString *) getCardName;

//Retrieves the IIN in the Card
- (NSString *) getCardIIN;

//Retrieves the Last 4 of the PAN
- (NSString *) getCardLast4;

//Retrieves the Expiration Date
- (NSString *) getCardExpDate;

//Retrieves the Service Code
- (NSString *) getCardServiceCode;

//Retrieves the Card Status
- (NSString *) getCardStatus;

//Retrieves the Track Decode Status
- (NSString *) getTrackDecodeStatus;

//Retrieve Response Type
- (NSString *) getResponseType;

//Sets the type of device to Open
-(void) setDeviceType: (UInt32)deviceType;

//Retrieves device opened status
- (BOOL) isDeviceOpened;

// Clears all the buffer that is stored during card swipe or command response
- (void) clearBuffers;
//Retrieves the battery Level
- (long) getBatteryLevel;
//Retrieves the swipe count
- (long) getSwipeCount;
//Gets the current version of the SDK.
- (NSString *) getSDKVersion;
//Retrieves the Operation Status
- (NSString *) getOperationStatus;
//Config Functions
- (NSString *) getEncryptionStatus;
//Config Functions



@end
```

My ApiDefinition looks like this

```
    using System;
using System.Drawing;

using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.AudioToolbox;
using MonoTouch.ExternalAccessory;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;


namespace CreditCardReaderIDynamoDLL
{



    [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
    [Model]
    interface NSStreamDelegate
    {

    }

    [BaseType(typeof(NSObject),Delegates=new string[]{"WeakDelegate"},Events = new Type[] {(typeof(NSStreamDelegate))})]
    interface MISCRA{

        [Export("delegate"), NullAllowed]
        NSObject WeakDelegate{get; set;}

        [Wrap("WeakDelegate")][New]
        NSStreamDelegate Delegate{get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("cardIIN")]
        NSString CardIIN{[Bind("cardIIN")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("cardData")]
        NSString CardData{[Bind("cardData")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("cardLast4")]
        NSString CardLast4{[Bind("cardLast4")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("cardName")]
        NSString CardName{[Bind("cardName")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("cardExpDate")]
        NSString cardExpDate{[Bind("cardExpDate")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("cardServiceCode")]
        NSString CardServiceCode{[Bind("cardServiceCode")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("cardStatus")]
        NSString CardStatus{[Bind("cardStatus")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("responseData")]
        NSString ResponseData{[Bind("responseData")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("maskedTracks")]
        NSString MaskedTracks{[Bind("maskedTracks")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("stdTrack1")]
        NSString StdTrack1{[Bind("stdTrack1")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("stdTrack2")]
        NSString StdTrack2{[Bind("stdTrack2")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("stdTrack3")]
        NSString StdTrack3{[Bind("stdTrack3")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("encryptedTrack1")]
        NSString EncryptedTrack1{[Bind("encryptedTrack1")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("encryptedTrack2")]
        NSString EncryptedTrack2{[Bind("encryptedTrack2")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("encryptedTrack3")]
        NSString EncryptedTrack3{[Bind("encryptedTrack3")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("encryptionStatus")]
        NSString EncryptionStatus{[Bind("encryptionStatus")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("maskedTrack1")]
        NSString MaskedTrack1{[Bind("maskedTrack1")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("maskedTrack2")]
        NSString MaskedTrack2{[Bind("maskedTrack2")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("maskedTrack3")]
        NSString MaskedTrack3{[Bind("maskedTrack3")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("trackDecodeStatus")]
        NSString TrackDecodeStatus{[Bind("trackDecodeStatus")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("encryptedMagneprint")]
        NSString EncryptedMagneprint{[Bind("encryptedMagneprint")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("magneprintStatus")]
        NSString MagneprintStatus{[Bind("magneprintStatus")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("deviceSerialNumber")]
        NSString DeviceSerialNumber{[Bind("deviceSerialNumber")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("deviceSerialNumberMagTek")]
        NSString DeviceSerialNumberMagTek{[Bind("deviceSerialNumberMagTek")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("encrypedSessionID")]
        NSString EncrypedSessionID{[Bind("encrypedSessionID")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("deviceKSN")]
        NSString DeviceKSN{[Bind("deviceKSN")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("deviceFirmware")]
        NSString DeviceFirmware{[Bind("deviceFirmware")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("deviceName")]
        NSString deviceName{[Bind("deviceName")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("deviceCaps")]
        NSString DeviceCaps{[Bind("deviceCaps")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("deviceStatus")]
        NSString DeviceStatus{[Bind("deviceStatus")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("tlvVersion")]
        NSString TlvVersion{[Bind("tlvVersion")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("devicePartNumber")]
        NSString DevicePartNumber{[Bind("devicePartNumber")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("capMSR")]
        NSString CapMSR{[Bind("capMSR")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("capTracks")]
        NSString CapTracks{[Bind("capTracks")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("capMagStripeEncryption")]
        NSString CapMagStripeEncryption{[Bind("capMagStripeEncryption")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("MaskedPAN")]
        NSString MaskedPAN{[Bind("MaskedPAN")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("additionalInfoTrack1")]
        NSString AdditionalInfoTrack1{[Bind("additionalInfoTrack1")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("additionalInfoTrack2")]
        NSString AdditionalInfoTrack2{[Bind("additionalInfoTrack2")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("responseType")]
        NSString ResponseType{[Bind("responseType")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("batteryLevel")]
        NSString BatteryLevel{[Bind("batteryLevel")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("swipeCount")]
        NSString swipeCount{[Bind("swipeCount")]get; set;}

        /*  [ExportAttribute("rioUnit")]
        AudioUnit RioUnit{[Bind("rioUnit")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("inputProc")]
        AURenderCallbackStruct InputProc{ [Bind("inputProc")]get; set; }*/

        [ExportAttribute("thruFormat")]
        AudioStreamBasicDescription ThruFormat{[Bind("thruFormat")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("bufferlist")]
        AudioBuffer Bufferlist{[Bind("bufferlist")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("buf")]
        AudioBuffer Buf{[Bind("buf")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("buf1")]
        AudioBuffer Buf1{[Bind("buf1")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("isDeviceConnected")]
        bool IsDeviceConnected{ [Bind("isDeviceConnected")]get; set; }

        [ExportAttribute("eventMask")]
        long EventMask{[Bind("eventMask")]get; set;}

        [ExportAttribute("devCapabilities")]
        long devCapabilities{ [Bind("devCapabilities")]get; set; }

        [ExportAttribute("commandBits")]
        Byte CommandBits{ [Bind("commandBits")]get; set; }

        [ExportAttribute("commandBitsIndex")]
        int CommandBitsIndex{ [Bind("commandBitsIndex")]get; set; }

        [ExportAttribute("_accessory")]
        EAAccessory _Accessory{ [Bind("_accessory")]get; set; }

        [ExportAttribute("_session")]
        EASession _Session{ [Bind("_session")]get; set; }

        [ExportAttribute("eaAccessory")]
        EAAccessoryManager EaAccessory{ [Bind("eaAccessory")]get; set; }

        [ExportAttribute("dataFromiDynamo")]
        NSMutableAttributedString DataFromiDynamo{ [Bind("dataFromiDynamo")]get; set; }

        [ExportAttribute("deviceProtocolString")]
        NSMutableAttributedString DeviceProtocolString{ [Bind("deviceProtocolString")]get; set; }

        [ExportAttribute("configParams")]
        NSMutableAttributedString configParams{ [Bind("configParams")]get; set; }


        [Export ("openDevice")]
        bool OpenDevice();

        [Export ("closeDevice")]
        bool CloseDevice();

        [Export ("isDeviceConnected")]
        bool IssDeviceConnected();

        [Export ("getTrack1Masked")]
        NSString GetTrack1Masked();

        [Export ("getTrack2Masked")]
        NSString GetTrack2Masked();

        [Export ("getTrack3Masked")]
        NSString getTrack3Masked();

        [Export ("getMaskedTracks")]
        NSString GetMaskedTracks();

        [Export ("getTrack1")]
        NSString GetTrack1();

        [Export ("getTrack2")]
        NSString GetTrack2();

        [Export ("GetTrack3")]
        NSString GetTrack3();

        [Export ("getMagnePrint")]
        NSString GetMagnePrint();

        [Export ("getMagnePrintStatus")]
        NSString GetMagnePrintStatus();

        [Export ("getDeviceSerial")]
        NSString GetDeviceSerial();

        [Export ("getMagTekDeviceSerial")]
        NSString GetMagTekDeviceSerial();

        [Export ("getFirmware")]
        NSString GetFirmware();

        [Export ("getDeviceName")]
        NSString GetDeviceName();

        [Export ("getDeviceCaps")]
        NSString GetDeviceCaps();

        [Export ("getDeviceStatus")]
        NSString GetDeviceStatus();

        [Export ("getTLVVersion")]
        NSString GetTLVVersion();

        [Export ("getDevicePartNumber")]
        NSString GetDevicePartNumber();

        [Export ("getKSN")]
        NSString GetKSN();

        [Export ("getTagValue:")]
        NSString SetTagValue(UInt32 tag);

        [Export ("getCapMSR")]
        NSString GetCapMSR();

        [Export ("getCapTracks")]
        NSString GetCapTracks();

        [Export ("GetCapMagStripeEncryption")]
        NSString GetCapMagStripeEncryption();

        [Export ("sendCommandToDevice:")]
        void sendCommandToDevice(NSString pData);

        [Export ("setDeviceProtocolString:")]
        void SetDeviceProtocolString(NSString pData);

        [Export ("setConfigurationParams:")]
        void SetConfigurationParams(NSString pData);

        [Export ("listenForEvents:")]
        void listenForEvents(UInt32 _event);

        [Export ("getDeviceType")]
        int GetDeviceType();

        [Export ("getCardPANLength")]
        int GetCardPANLength();

        [Export ("getSessionID:")]
        NSString GetSessionID();

        [Export ("getResponseData")]
        NSString GetResponseData();

        [Export ("getCardName")]
        NSString GetCardName();

        [Export ("getCardIIN")]
        NSString getCardIIN();

        [Export ("getCardLast4")]
        NSString GetCardLast4();

        [Export ("getCardExpDate")]
        NSString GetCardExpDate();

        [Export ("getCardServiceCode")]
        NSString GetCardServiceCode();

        [Export ("getCardStatus")]
        NSString GetCardStatus();

        [Export ("getTrackDecodeStatus")]
        NSString GetTrackDecodeStatus();

        [Export ("getResponseType")]
        NSString GetResponseType();

        [Export ("setDeviceType:")]
        void SetDeviceType(UInt32 deviceType);

        [Export ("isDeviceOpened")]
        bool IsDeviceOpened();

        [Export ("clearBuffers")]
        void ClearBuffers();

        [Export ("getBatteryLevel")]
        long GetBatteryLevel();

        [Export ("getSwipeCount")]
        long GetSwipeCount();

        [Export ("getSDKVersion")]
        NSString GetSDKVersion();

        [Export ("getOperationStatus")]
        NSString GetOperationStatus();

        [Export ("getEncryptionStatus")]
        NSString GetEncryptionStatus();

    }


}
```

And lastly my linkwith file is as follows

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime;

[assembly: LinkWith ("libMTSCRA.a", LinkTarget =  LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.ArmV6 | LinkTarget.Simulator, 
                     Frameworks = "AudioToolbox ExternalAccessory Foundation", ForceLoad = true)]
```

When I import the library in a a normal monotouch Ipad project I get the following build output. (not the ful output, ran out of characters)

```
    Compiling to native code\
/var/folders/g2/j4prljqd2w58pfd2bf0hm9pc0000gn/T/tmp7967f93f.tmp/System.Core.dll.armv7.o /var/folders/g2/j4prljqd2w58pfd2bf0hm9pc0000gn/T/tmp7967f93f.tmp/MonoTouch.Dialog-1.dll.armv7.o /var/folders/g2/j4prljqd2w58pfd2bf0hm9pc0000gn/T/tmp7967f93f.tmp/mscorlib.dll.armv7.o /var/folders/g2/j4prljqd2w58pfd2bf0hm9pc0000gn/T/tmp7967f93f.tmp/System.dll.armv7.o /var/folders/g2/j4prljqd2w58pfd2bf0hm9pc0000gn/T/tmp7967f93f.tmp/monotouch.dll.armv7.o /Users/dylanvdmerwe/Desktop/Projects/Affinion/trunk/CreditCardReaderIDynamoIpadDemo/CreditCardReaderIDynamoIpadDemo/obj/Release/mtouch-cache/main..armv7.cache.V7WUEG1CYIbzGQyRJadXq2I83LQ=.o /Users/dylanvdmerwe/Desktop/Projects/Affinion/trunk/CreditCardReaderIDynamoIpadDemo/CreditCardReaderIDynamoIpadDemo/obj/Release/mtouch-cache/registrar.armv7.cache.oz4CLqSH9MR1-CuVC2OCHFSKN8A=.o -o /var/folders/g2/j4prljqd2w58pfd2bf0hm9pc0000gn/T/tmp7967f93f.tmp/CreditCardReaderIDynamoIpadDemo -framework CFNetwork -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework AudioToolbox -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreGraphics -framework ExternalAccessory -lz -liconv -u _mono_pmip -u _monotouch_create_managed_ref -u _monotouch_release_managed_ref -u _monotouch_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr -u _monotouch_IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr -u _CloseZStream -u _CreateZStream -u _Flush -u _ReadZStream -u _WriteZStream -lmono-2.0 -lmonotouch -L/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib  -force_load /var/folders/g2/j4prljqd2w58pfd2bf0hm9pc0000gn/T/tmp7967f93f.tmp/libMTSCRA.a\
    Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:\
      "operator delete(void*)", referenced from:\
          -[MTSCRA hexStringtoBytes:] in libMTSCRA.a(MTSCRA.o)\
          hasData(void*, unsigned long*, AudioTimeStamp const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, AudioBufferList*)in libMTSCRA.a(MTSCRA.o)\
          composeCommand(int, long*, int, unsigned char*, int, int*)in libMTSCRA.a(MTSCRA.o)\
          AudioReader::processSamples(long)   in libMTSCRA.a(AudioReader.o)\
          AudioReader::copyResponseData()       in libMTSCRA.a(AudioReader.o)\
          AudioReader::initData()      in libMTSCRA.a(AudioReader.o)\
          AudioReader::tlvDecode(int*)   in libMTSCRA.a(AudioReader.o)\
          ...\
      "operator new[](unsigned long)", referenced from:\
          -[MTSCRA hexStringtoBytes:] in libMTSCRA.a(MTSCRA.o)\
          hasData(void*, unsigned long*, AudioTimeStamp const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, AudioBufferList*)in libMTSCRA.a(MTSCRA.o)\
          composeCommand(int, long*, int, unsigned char*, int, int*)in libMTSCRA.a(MTSCRA.o)\
          AudioReader::copyResponseData()       in libMTSCRA.a(AudioReader.o)\
          AudioReader::manchesterDecodeUartforResponseData(int, unsigned char*)in libMTSCRA.a(AudioReader.o)\
          AudioReader::ByteArrayToHex(unsigned char*, int)in libMTSCRA.a(AudioReader.o)\
          AudioReader::manchesterDecodeUart(int, int*)in libMTSCRA.a(AudioReader.o)\
          ...\
      "operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:\
          AudioReader::processSamples(long)   in libMTSCRA.a(AudioReader.o)\
          AudioReader::processSamples(long)   in libMTSCRA.a(AudioReader.o)\
      "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:\
          -[MTSCRA getConfigurationParams:] in libMTSCRA.a(MTSCRA.o)\
          -[MTSCRA setCardData:] in libMTSCRA.a(MTSCRA.o)\
          -[MTSCRA getCardIINFromMaskTracks] in libMTSCRA.a(MTSCRA.o)\
          -[MTSCRA getCardLast4FromMaskTracks] in libMTSCRA.a(MTSCRA.o)\
          -[MTSCRA getMaskedPAN] in libMTSCRA.a(MTSCRA.o)\
          -[MTSCRA getTrack1AdditionalInfo] in libMTSCRA.a(MTSCRA.o)\
          -[MTSCRA getTrack2AdditionalInfo] in libMTSCRA.a(MTSCRA.o)\
          ...\
      "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:\
          -[MTSCRA getConfigurationParams:] in libMTSCRA.a(MTSCRA.o)\
          -[MTSCRA setCardData:] in libMTSCRA.a(MTSCRA.o)\
          -[MTSCRA getCardIINFromMaskTracks] in libMTSCRA.a(MTSCRA.o)\
          -[MTSCRA getCardLast4FromMaskTracks] in libMTSCRA.a(MTSCRA.o)\
          -[MTSCRA getMaskedPAN] in libMTSCRA.a(MTSCRA.o)\
          -[MTSCRA getTrack1AdditionalInfo] in libMTSCRA.a(MTSCRA.o)\
          -[MTSCRA getTrack2AdditionalInfo] in libMTSCRA.a(MTSCRA.o)\
          ...\
      "___gxx_personality_sj0", referenced from:\
          AudioReader::processSamples(long)   in libMTSCRA.a(AudioReader.o)\
          AudioReader::processSamples(long)   in libMTSCRA.a(AudioReader.o)\
          AudioReader::processSamples(long)   in libMTSCRA.a(AudioReader.o)\
          AudioReader::processSamples(long)   in libMTSCRA.a(AudioReader.o)\
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7\
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status\
    \
    error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log.\
    \
    ---------------------- Done ----------------------\
    \
    Build: 1 error, 4 warnings\
```

I have also tried adding AudioUnit in the linkwith file and I get a framework not found error. I have also tried adding CoreAudio to the same effect.

Sorry about the code dump. I hope someone can help me out there, stuck in a hole at the moment.

Comment: Is your static library build for armv7? If so, you might miss a native dependency for your native .a

Comment: Is this a c++ library you're trying to bind?

Comment: Jean-Louis the missing symbols are from C++ so your `[LinkWith]` attribute should state this. @StephaneDelcroix you should create an answer (instead of the comment :-)

Comment: @poupou Sébastien, as I was looking at the trace from my phone I wasn't sure about this being the right answer. ;)

Answer (score 3):

As the missing references to new() tend to indicate, you're probably binding a c++ library (or a wrapper to a c++ lib).

It your library depend on a (c++) other one, add a [LinkWith] attribute for that one too

And keep in mind that any c++ library should have the property IsCxx=true set in its LinkWith attribute

```
[assembly: LinkWith ("libMTSCRA.a", IsCxx=true, LinkTarget =  LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.ArmV6 | LinkTarget.Simulator, Frameworks = "AudioToolbox ExternalAccessory Foundation", ForceLoad = true)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That was the problem. @poupou  After making that change I ran into duplicate symbol errors and after further investigation (some quick googling) I came across [this wonderful link](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/MagTek.iDynamo) dont know why I didnt come across this earlier. If you havent noticed I am currently busy trying to implement that exact same library.  It looks like you have already come up with a solution for the duplicate symbol errors so just wanted to thank you in advance :)